# FireFox v22.0 won't download and display XBAP anymore

Tags: xaml, firefox, download, components, xbap

I've recently upgraded to FireFox 22. Originally, a legacy XBAP I use always opened correctly in FireFox and had no problems displaying or running. As of 22, it won't even attempt to download the application, let alone try and display it.

I have the windows Presentation Foundation 3.5.30729.1 (NPWPF.DLL) installed, which is the same version I have been using in older versions.

Can anyone shed some light on any changes that would have effected this?

Comment: williamtroup - have you tried my answer?

Comment: Sorry, this did not help.  I could not find any RDF files linked to the NPWPF.DLL file.  I also tried FireFox 22 on a fresh machine and copying over NPWPF.DLL and it still crashes

Comment: Do you have npwpf.dll in plugins folder?

Comment: yes, its currently in the plugins folder

Comment: no idea at the moment =(

Answer (score 1):

If it is some kind of legacy add-on - you should look for the description file - `RDF` - in your user profile.

Set the `em:maxVersion` to 22. (Or to 23 etc. if it will not work after next update)

*Update:*

You should also have `npwpf.dll` in Firefox plugins folder.